# Trying this again... live boot on arm device

Tags: android, live-cd

To those who feel this is a duplicate, please first read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD to better understand the concept of what I am asking. Also note that the live-cd tag specifically addresses "Questions related to live CDs, which allow you to test drive Ubuntu without installing it."

I am looking for information on running Ubuntu on an arm device specifically *without* installing it, e.g a Live Boot. Installing Ubuntu on a Transformer is sufficiently documented, and I understand the process. However, I can find only a little information regarding a Live Ubuntu session booted into ram (such as possible with the PC Ubuntu CD) as _*opposed*_ to installing it on the device. This bit that I found confirmed that it can be done, but did not clarify.

Can anybody comment on any experiences that they have either had or have heard of regarding this issue? Thanks you, and I am sorry about double posting but I was most definitely miss understood.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't see any documentation on this, but this would be extremely useful. I'll tell you why.

Instead of running a normal computer to stay on irc chat to keep up with the lastest security news or to connect to "ubuntu" and open source irc servers, you can use a raspberry pi at 5 watt max to save power, (it uses no power) it's more reliable, it's more secure because it's a one app appliance, and frees up your computer, and you can be always on.

How would the live boot be useful?
it's more reliable...because an irc chat program would not need to write logs onto the boot media and wear it out, it can write to ram.

Sure, you can probably create a ramdisk and change logging directories but maybe not every program will play nicely and things are getting complicated.

One way this can be done:

The Raspberry Pi verion B has HDMI, 512MiB of RAM, a low power Arm processor and 3 usb ports, one usb port is taken by a RJ45 network port, so you only have 2.

Supposedly, with a booting sd card, one port would be taken, one left but we still need a few more ports for keyboard and mouse. a usb hub can solve this problem and maybe allow for a fourth port [Live Boot] [Hub=> kb, mouse, *_*] for storage.

Something live-boot-like would be nice because any security breach means nothing if sd cards can be write protected but this means you can't write a log except in memory or only on additional storage or through the network. If the raspberry Pi had vga, we would be all set. You would have to definitely secure the network and update the software securely after a reboot and that's it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This seems like it is, at least in part, an answer to the question, but it's worded as though you're trying to start or participate in a discussion. To make this clearer for people searching for help (so they know this post might help them), and to decrease the likelihood that this post will be considered not-an-answer and deleted, I recommend rewording this,  and also removing anything that is actually a question (rather than a proposed solution) and posting it on a forum (rather than a question-answer site like Ask Ubuntu).